# Video Card Shortage - Running Blender CPU only (using a newer 12th gen Core i5)

Tags: rendering, gpu

The current PC I am using as I learn Blender is woefully slow (3rd gen Core i7 3770, AMD Radeon 7970 GPU (3 Gb), 8 Gb DDR Ram on the motherboard). I don't think that GPU is even supported so right now I have blender running CPU only, with a very outdated CPU. I'm experiencing render times in excess of 6 hours unsurprisingly (I'd say scenes of medium to high complexity...no animation). So I am in the midst of configuring the best PC that fits in my budget. The problem is right now I can't source a GPU for anywhere near retail so I may have to wait and use CPU only rendering for a few months. Can anyone give me an idea of render times (for the BMW reference scene) with the configuration below? Also interested to know what the render times would look like in comparison once I do add a GPU (GeForce RTX 3060). I know these are fairly entry level specs, but hoping I will see much fast times with my Core i5 12600K vs circa 2012 Core i3 3rd Gen with AMD HD9790.

Intel Core i5 12600K, 32 Gb DDR4 RAM, 1 Tb SSD, MSI PTO Z690-A Motherboard.

Sincere Thanks!!

Comment: Check Gamer's Nexus on YouTube which includes Blender in their gamut of tests for benchmarks.  They also have well managed timecodes and are just great in general.  Tech Jesus

Comment: Thanks @Allen Simpson!